# How to add up the number of tries a user inputs a number until it is correct

Tags: c++, addition

I almost have this done but I keep running into a problem I need for the code to display the number of tries a user enters a number, when I start the program it shows tries : 0 as it should but if I guess above or below the random number it will not display the number of tries until the second input of higher or lower, it works fine though if I enter the random number.

```
//bracketing search c++ beginner challenge
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

    int main() {
    int guess; //Initializing the guess integer variable
    int answer; //Initializing the answer integer variable
    int t = 0;
    srand(time(NULL)); // Prep for random number
    answer = rand() % 100; // random number 0 - 99
    cout << "hello please pick a number from zero to ninety nine " <<     endl; //Prompt the user to enter a number
    cout << answer << endl; // just here to test what happens when number is correct
    cout << "number of tries is : "<< t << endl;
    cin >> guess; // getting the input of the guess variable
    t++;


    while (guess == answer) {
        cout << "value of tries is : " << t << endl;
        cout << "You picked the right number " << endl; //while loop, guess equal to answer then code executes, continue at the end so that it will ask until you guess the right number  
        break;
    }


    while (guess < answer) { //while loop guess smaller than answer
        cout << "Pick a higher number " << endl; // Prompt the user to pick a higher number
        cin >> guess; // input for the guess variable
        t++;
        cout << "value of tries is : " << t << endl;
        continue; // brings back to the beggining of the loop
    }


    while (guess > answer) { //while guess variable is bigger than answer variable executes the code
        cout << "Pick a lower number " << endl; //prompt the user to pick a lower number
        cin >> guess; //Get input on user's next or first guess
        t++;
        cout << "value of tries is : " << t << endl;
        continue; //brings the user back to the beggining of the while loop
    }

    system("pause"); // pauses system so the user can see what is in the command window 

    return 0; // return a value of 0 marking the end of the program

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `while` loops. Most should be `if`s. You need one `while` that does not end until guess is correct. (I use a `do/while` loop):

```
....
do {
    cout << "number of tries is : "<< t << endl;

    cout << "hello please pick a number from zero to ninety nine " << endl;
    // TODO: Add error checking in case user does not enter a number
    cin >> guess; // getting the input of the guess variable
    t++;

    // change to if
    if (guess < answer) {
        cout << "Pick a higher number " << endl; // Prompt the user to pick a higher number
    }

    // Change to else if
    else if (guess > answer) {
        cout << "Pick a lower number " << endl; //prompt the user to pick a lower number
    }
} while (guess != answer);  // Loop until correct
```